# NavigationManager redirect to Identity cshtml not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I have a login button, which should redirect me to the Login form of asp.net identity

So I have a button with:
`Click="@(_ => _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login"))"`

But when I click it, the url in the browser changes but I'm getting a 404 error. Now, when I do a reload with F5 the login form appears.
Why is that?

Comment: navigate to has additional parameter (true/false) for force reloading

Comment: @spzvtbg Wow. I didn't think it was that easy. But thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Click="@(_ => _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login", true))"
```

there is an overload which allowes for force reload!